# Picking top n% percent of elements from matrix rows, different number of elements on each row

Tags: r, loops, matrix, picking

I have a problem with picking the top n% largest and smallest element's
from each data matrix row. Specifically, I would like to find the column numbers of those top n% elements. This would not be a problem if each row had the same number of non-NA-elements, but in this situation the number of picked elements is different for each row. Here's an example of the situation (the real data matrix is 195x1030 so I'wont be using it here), where top 40% are picked

```
data=     
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1   NA   100  98   200  78   80   35   NA    55
[2,]   32   67   15   73   NA   12   91   230  3     99
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   45   53   26   112  64   80    41
[4,]   54   38   60   70   163  69   109  205  5     31
[5,]   107  28   296  254  30   40   NA   18   28    90
```

The resulting top 40% column numbers matrixes should look like these (the number of picked elements is calculated by rounding down, as the function as.integer does)

```
largest=                              smallest=
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]                   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  
[1,]    5   3    4    NA              [1,]    1   8    10   NA
[2,]    8   10   7    NA              [2,]    9   6    3    NA
[3,]    7   9    NA   NA              [3,]    6   10   NA   NA
[4,]    8   5    7    4               [4,]    9   10   2    1
[5,]    3   4    1    10              [5,]    8   9    2    5
```

So the top numbers are selected looking only at the non-NA-elements of the rows. For example the first row of data matrix contains only 8 non-NA-numbers and thus 40%*8=3,2~ 3 elements are selected. This creates the NA's to the resulting matrixes.

Once again, I tried using a for-loop (this code is to finding the largest 40%):

```
   largest <- matrix(rep(NA, 20), nrow = 5)
 for(i in 1:5){
   largest[i,]<-order(data[i,], decreasing=T)   
 [1:as.integer(0.4*nrow(data[complete.cases(data[,i]),]))]
 }
```

but R returns an error: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length", which I think means that since not all the elements of the original largest-matrix are not replaced while looping, this for-loop can't be used. Am I right?

How could this sort of picking be done?

Comment: I don't understand (yet) your expected output. In `largest` why is element `[1,4] = NA` and not `7`? Column 7 contains the fourth largest number in row 1 of `data`. Similarly for element `[2,4]`, and so on for the other `NA` entries.

Comment: It's because I would like to pick just the top 40% of the non-NA-elements. For example for the first row, which contains 8 non-NA-elements, the number of picked elements is 0,4*8=3,2. This is rounded down to 3. Thus the first row the largest-matrix should contain only 3 numbers, not 4. I'll specify the question, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Do you need the top/bottom n% sorted or would the positions of the top/bottom n% suffice? If so, I'd have a solution ready.

Comment: I hadn't thought of it, but actually I don't need the sorting! Just the positions would be enough.

Comment: Too slow :) @MauritsEvers got you covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reproduces your expected output

```
# Determine number of columns for output matrix as
# maximum of 40% of all non-NA values per row
ncol <- max(floor(apply(mat, 1, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))) * 0.4))

# Top 40% largest
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) {
    n <- floor(sum(!is.na(x)) * 0.4);
    replace(rep(NA, ncol), 1:n, order(x, decreasing = T)[1:n])
}))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    5    3    4   NA
#[2,]    8   10    7   NA
#[3,]    7    9   NA   NA
#[4,]    8    5    7    4
#[5,]    3    4    1   NA


# Top 40% smallest
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x) {
    n <- floor(sum(!is.na(x)) * 0.4);
    replace(rep(NA, ncol), 1:n, order(x, decreasing = F)[1:n])
}))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    8   10   NA
#[2,]    9    6    3   NA
#[3,]    6   10   NA   NA
#[4,]    9   10    2    1
#[5,]    8    2    9   NA
```

Explanation: We first determine the max number of columns for both output matrices; we then loop through `mat` row-by-row, determine the row-specific number `n` of non-`NA` entries corresponding to 40% of all non-`NA` numbers in that row, and return a column `vector` of the top 40% decreasing/increasing entries padded with `NA`s. Final transpose gives the expected output.

Comment: Thank you very much, this work's like a charm! I am truy grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my (less exact and very similar) answer as it is in form of a function, which might be handy:

```
toppct <- function(x, p, largest = TRUE){
  t(apply(x, 1, function(y){
    c(which(y %in% sort(y, decreasing = largest)[1:floor(length(which(!is.na(y)))*p)]), 
      rep(NA, floor(length(y)*p) - floor(length(which(!is.na(y)))*p)))
  }))
}
```

This produces the output in the question, just without sorting the top percent positions. For `smallest`, just set `largest = FALSE`.

```
> toppct(mat, .4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    4    5   NA
[2,]    7    8   10   NA
[3,]    7    9   NA   NA
[4,]    4    5    7    8
[5,]    1    3    4   NA

> toppct(mat, .4, largest = FALSE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    8   10   NA
[2,]    3    6    9   NA
[3,]    6   10   NA   NA
[4,]    1    2    9   10
[5,]    2    8    9   NA
```

I want to emphasize that I think Maurits' answer is the one to accept, as he gets the output exactly as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for this one! Tried it and it's really handy.

Comment: Like the functional approach. Very neat. +1